# Custom module blocks: where to put html code?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I have a custom module that implements hook_block_view. I would like to know where should I put extensive html code for a block content.

For example:

```
$block['title'] = t('TEST');
$block['content'] = '<div id="user-custom-block">';
$block['content'] .= ... 50 LINES OF HTML.
$block['content'] .= '</div>';
```

What I did so far was to create a **.tpl.php** file and put all this code there, and then only call:

```
$block['title'] = t('TEST');
$block['content'] = theme('user_custom_block');
```

Is it correct?

If yes, so far, so good. But what if I have a "complex" logic inside of this block content?

For example:

```
$block['title'] = t('TEST');
for...
  $block['content'] = '<div id="user-custom-block">';
  if:
    $block['content'] .= ... 50 LINES OF HTML.
  endif;
  $block['content'] .= '</div>';
endfor;
etc
etc
```

Is this still ok to use in a **.tpl.php** file? If not, which approach should I use?

Should I use something like this?

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_view().
 */
function custom_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my-block-id':
      $block['subject'] = t('Block Name');
      $block['content'] = custom_contents();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * custom html block
 * @return string
 */
function custom_contents() {
  return '
      </p><div class="body">
        Hello World, this is a example custom Block
      </div><p>
    ';
}
```

Comment: I would personally use a .tpl.php file but i believe both is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal should be to keep all processing out of the template file. Treat the template as a template - just some HTML and in some places, you print out variables.

From what you are describing though, it would be most useful to use a template for the '50 lines of HTML'. It is one thing to maintain a few lines of HTML in a PHP function, but 50 sounds like a nightmare.

```
<!-- my-template.tpl.php -->
<div class="50-lines-of-html">
  <?php echo $this; ?>
  <?php echo $that; ?>
</div>
```

Next, create some function that runs your for ... loop and builds the content using that template:

```
function process_my_things($things) {
  $output = '';
  foreach ($things as $thing) {
    if ($it_is == TRUE) {
      // do some stuff with $thing
      $output .= theme('my-template', array('this' => $this, 'that', => $that));
    }
  }
  return $output
}
```

Note that this can be a theme function too, but it doesn't have to be unless you want to allow overrides.

Finally, use another theme function or a template as a wrapper to arrange what you've got. You could even just use $block['content'] here as above:

```
$block['content'] = '<div id="my-wrapper">';
$block['content'] .= process_my_things($things);
$block['content'] .= '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could improve that with 2 different options:
1) Creating a theme function
2) Creating a template file (tpl)

The tpl may be a cleaner option, but they are both similar. In both cases, you should pass preprocessed variables instead of putting the logic inside the theme function/tpl file.

Also, note that the literal strings should go through the t() function.